# How can I search through members that aren't friends of the current user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a members table and a member requests table.  In the requests table are columns for author id and recipient id and also status.  If the current user has a row with their ID as the author id and another member as the recipient id(or vice versa) and the status is 1, then the user is friends with that member.  I would like to set up a search system that can be used to find members that the user isn't friends with by the name they type in.  The query below is used to find the user's current friends by a name they type in.  How can I search through members that the user isn't friends with?

```
SELECT 
  r.author_id, m.member_id, m.display_name
FROM member_requests AS r
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON m.member_id = r.author_id
WHERE r.recipient_id = 1 
  AND r.status = 1 
  AND m.display_name LIKE "John%"
UNION SELECT 
  r.recipient_id, m.member_id, m.display_name
FROM member_requests AS r
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON m.member_id = r.recipient_id
WHERE r.author_id = 1 
  AND r.status = 1
  AND m.display_name LIKE "John%"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb0d4d/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a lot easier than you think. Based off my answer from the last question, if you have a list of members someone IS friends with, you can search the members table for IDs that are not in that list.

Try this:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM members
WHERE member_id NOT IN(
  SELECT recipient_id AS friends
  FROM member_requests 
  WHERE author_id = 1 AND status = 1 
  UNION
  SELECT author_id AS friends
  FROM member_requests
  WHERE recipient_id = 1 AND status = 1)
AND member_id != 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021d7/34).